# How can I do this jQuery code in a more reduced way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('#menu .selected').removeClass('selected');
      $('#homel').addClass('selected');
      $('#home').slideDown(150, function() {
        $('#public').slideUp(200);
        $('#login').slideUp(200);
        $('#faq').slideUp(200);

      });
```

Which, as you can guess, hides and shows `div` boxes. In that example `#homel` is the Home link, and `#home` is the home div. This looks ok, but if I want to add a new box, for example, `#register`I have to add here and on every other box code (`#public`, `#login` and `#faq`) the code: `$('#register').slideUp(200);`
Is there any way that can be simplified and made generic for all?

### EDIT: jsFiddle link for the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ5Q4/1/)

Comment: Can we see some of your HTML markup?

Comment: Need to provide some code for this, or a jsfiddle

Comment: let me jsfiddle an example :)

Comment: Have you tried to enclose #public, #login. #faq, ... inside a <div>?

Comment: @macjohn yes I have all those divs inside a #content div. Everyone else: I added a jsfiddle link

Comment: I updated my answer. It's much more cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/LQ5Q4/2/) is a different solution. I gave all h3 divs a common class and select them with one selector. This way it's you don't have to change your code everytime you add another div. There is also a function for `slideUp`. Now all routes can use same function, no need for lots of anonymous functions.

This is the final result;

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="./#/home" class="selected" id="homel">Home</a> <a href="./#/public" id="publicl">Public</a> <a href="./#/users/login" id="loginl">Login</a> <a href="./#/faq" id="faql">FAQ</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="home" class="h3div">
        <h3>Welcome</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="public"class="h3div">
        <h3>Public</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="login"class="h3div">
        <h3>Login</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="register"class="h3div">
        <h3>Register</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="faq" class="h3div">
        <h3>Frequently Asked Questions</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.routes({
        '/': function() {
            $('#home').slideDown(200);
        },
        '/home': function() {
            menuSlideUpDown('home');
        },
        '/public': function() {
            menuSlideUpDown('public');
        },
        '/users/:what': function(params) {
            if (params.what == "login") {
                menuSlideUpDown('login');
            } else if (params.what == "register") {
                menuSlideUpDown('login');
            }
        },
        '/faq': function() {
            menuSlideUpDown('faq');
        }
    });
});

function menuSlideUpDown(item) {
    $('#menu a').removeClass('selected').filter('#' + item + 'l').addClass('selected');
    $('#' + item).slideDown(150, function() {
        $('.h3div').not(this).slideUp(150);
    });
}
```

And working example of final result is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/LQ5Q4/3/).

Answer (score 4):

Well you could give those three things a class and use that to operate on them (the "public", "login", and "faq" elements), or:

```
$('#public, #login, #faq').slideUp(200);
```

If you gave those things a class then you'd just say

```
$('.slideMeUp').slideUp(200);
```

or whatever. If you only want to affect those inside the outer container:

```
$('#home').slideDown(300, function() {
  $(this).find('.slideMeUp').slideUp(200);
});
```

*edit* — ah OK well now that I look at your markup I see what the deal is.  In a case like that, personally I'd use a "data-" attribute to relate the `<a>` elements in the menu to the page sections that they're supposed to control.  To do that, the menu tags would look like this:

```
<a href="./#/home" class="menu-item selected" id="homel" data-section='home'>Home</a>
```

The page sections should also have a class:

```
    <div id="home" class='menu-section'>
        <h3>Welcome</h3>
    </div>
```

Now, I'm not familiar with how that "routes" plugin works, but that should make it a lot easier to control things.  If you have a reference to one of the menu tags, then you can get the "id" value for the page section it controls with:

```
    var sectionId = $(menuItem).data('section');
```

Then you can remove class "selected" from all the ".menu-section" divs, add "selected" to the newly-selected one, and then slide all the others up:

```
    $('.content .menu-section:not(.selected)').slideUp(200);
```

Comment: haha feeling like an idiot :P I tried it without the commas :) looks a nice approach, thanks, though I want to see other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Moving everything into a function will shorten your code significantly.

```js
function collapse(e)
{
    $('#menu .selected').removeClass('selected');
      $('#'+e+'l').addClass('selected');
      $('#'+e).slideDown(150, function() {
        e=='public' || $('#public').slideUp(200);
        e=='login' || $('#login').slideUp(200);
        e=='faq' || $('#faq').slideUp(200);
        e=='home' || $('#home').slideUp(200);
      });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.routes({
    '/': function(){
      $('#home').slideDown(200);
    },
    '/home': function(){ collapse('home'); },
    '/public': function() { collapse('public'); },
    '/users/:what':function(params) {
      if(params.what == "login" || params.what == "register")
        collapse('login');
    },
    '/faq':function() { collapse('faq'); },
  });

});
```